# Optimize number of layers and neurons with an optimization algorithm

Tags: classification, matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I have a neural network that i want optimize number of hidden layers and neurons in every layer using an optimization algorithm like `Imperialist competitive algorithm`. As you know i should set limits of every variable for optimization. I can have maximum 2 layers. Besides this my system select best composition of features (among 21 features) based on cost function of my neural network (5-fold cross validation on test data) using that optimization algorithm. So my optimization algorithm has `21+2` variables. `21` for features and `2` for number of neurons in every layer. What is your idea and what do you recommend for boundary of number of neurons in every layer? I'm using `patternnet` in `MATLAB`. As you know we have difference composition of features and neural structure in calling cost function by optimization algorithm.